# Dynamic Routes for my list of projects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, I have JSON data with projects I want to dynamically link. I have created a component called "ProjectSingle" to display each one, however I can't seem to get the data to display.

```
const App = () => {

const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

const getProjects = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/projects')
  .then((res) =>{
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    setProjects(data);
  })
}

  useEffect(() => {
  getProjects();
  AOS.init({disable: 'mobile'});
  },[]);

  return (
    <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
      {projects.map( project =>(
      <Route exact path='/project/:slug' render={props => (
        <ProjectSingle {...props} project={project}/>
      )}/>
    ))}
      </Switch>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The requested JSON is below, I'm using "slug" to generate the slug.

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "title": "Project One",
      "image": "/img/wp-logo.png",
      "slug": "project-one",
      "key": 1
  },
  {
    "title": "Project Two",
    "image": "/img/wp-logo.png",
    "slug": "project-two",
    "key": 2
},

}
```

Although I'm not sure what data to put in my single component to get the data of the project iteration

```
const ProjectSingle = ({project}) => {

    const { slug } = useParams();

    return (
    <>
    <h1>{project.title}</h1>
    </>
    )
}

export default ProjectSingle;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you only need one `<Route path="/project/:slug" /> ... </Route>` assigned. The `:slug` param can be used to dynamically determine what the content of this route will be.

```
<Route
   exact
   path="/project/:slug"
   render={(props) => <ProjectSingle {...props} projects={projects} />}
/>
```

```
const ProjectSingle = ({projects}) => {

    const { slug } = useParams();
    const project = projects.find(p => p.slug === slug)

    return (
    <>
    <h1>{project.title}</h1>
    </>
    )
}

export default ProjectSingle;
```

The route's child (`ProjectSingle`) will then `useParams()` to retrieve the value associated with `:slug` and use that to find the correct `project` from `projects` to render.

There may be an even more clever way of using the `render()` of the route and determining the desired slug & project at that stage - making the `ProjectSingle` a pure component without any knowledge of routing.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot man, I was able to get the project data with this, I appreciate it.

Comment: On last question, every once and a while I get an error that says "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined " when I try to get the title of the ProductSingle, any reason why?

Comment: Cheers, `projects` is initially undefined and is defined asynchronously via `getProjects()` which runs `setProjects()`. The question you need to account for, is what should `< ProjectSingle />` render when the projects request has not yet completed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several important steps to achive this.

1. Include libraries like react-router, react-router-dom
2. Create a history
3. Render the Route with history
   4.Define Navigation to the routes

Here is a sample as per your requirement:
Note: As per your design the routes will render in the same page. I have updated it to be in single file here. complete working example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-sample-z6qgu?file=/src/ProjectSingle.js)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Router, Switch, Route, useParams } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import "./styles.css";

const history = createHistory();

const Footer = () => {
  return <div>Footer here.</div>;
};

const ProjectSingle = ({ project }) => {
  const { slug } = useParams();

  //TODO useEffect to get project details
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Details of {slug} </h1>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(project)}</div>
    </>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([
    {
      title: "Project One",
      image: "/img/wp-logo.png",
      slug: "project-one",
      key: 1
    },
    {
      title: "Project Two",
      image: "/img/wp-logo.png",
      slug: "project-two",
      key: 2
    }
  ]);

  /*const getProjects = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/projects')
    .then((res) =>{
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      setProjects(data);
    })
  }
  
    useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();
    AOS.init({disable: 'mobile'});
    },[]);
  */
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div className="App">
        {projects.map((project) => {
          return (
            <div key={project.key}>
              <Link to={`/project/${project.slug}`}> {project.title} </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <Switch>
          {projects.map((project) => (
            <Route
              key={project.key}
              exact
              path="/project/:slug"
              render={(props) => <ProjectSingle {...props} project={project} />}
            />
          ))}
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```